# Hello this is my package.json file. But Heroku tells me Application error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served

Tags: heroku, deployment

Hello this is my json file format and this works well on my local machine when I run node index.js.

```
{
  "name": "a-simple-nodejs-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Theodore Kelechukwu Onyejiaku",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

But Heroku tells me:
Application error 
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served...

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention engine in package.json as below

```
{
  "name": "a-simple-nodejs-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Theodore Kelechukwu Onyejiaku",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Check your Application Port in index.js. if you set to static port change as below:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
```

pass this port in your server listen method.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I did so. I already have PORT as process.env.PORT || 5000. I have already resolved this issue. Check my comment below.

Comment: if you find this answer helpful please select as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There was no start script in the json file so add => "start": "node index.js".
Fool code sample is below

```
{
  "name": "a-simple-nodejs-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node index.js",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Theodore Kelechukwu Onyejiaku",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```